# How to add data in a .json file?

Tags: javascript, json

I wanted to know how to add data in a .json file on a special event.

For example, when joining a server with the ID `326091420232581122`, it pushes this data in a `server.json` file.

```
{
 "326091420232581122": 2,
 "mode": 1
}
```

Can you help me please? :)

Comment: parse the `server.json` to a dictionary add id as new attribute and serialize it back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to require the file so that it becomes an object

```
let jsonFile = require('path/to/json/file');
```

Then you can modify the object inside `jsonFile` afterwhich you can then save this using `fs.writeFile()` from the `fs` package in Node.

```
const fs = require('fs');
let jsonFile = require('path/to/json/file');

fs.writeFile("/path/to/json/file", JSON.stringify(jsonFile), 'utf8', function (err) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```

Comment: Thanks. And where do I have to add the data?
Like

{"mode": 2}

Comment: You can directly modify jsonFile like `jsonFile.mode = 2`

Comment: OMG Thanks a loooot!